# Как лучше объединить две ветки?

Tags: c#, коллекции

Одна ветка соединяется с другой (`node` и `node_ser`). Внутри них множество вложенных узлов. В узлах содержится текст `text_` и прочее.

При соединении получаются две копии некоторых узлов.

Как исключить совпадающие?

```
foreach (var i in node_ser.collection_node)
{
    node.collection_node.Add(i);
}


public class Node
{
    public string name_ { get; set; }
    public string text_ { get; set; }

    public ObservableCollection<Node> collection_node { get; set; }
    public Node()
    {
        collection_node = new ObservableCollection<Node>();
    }
}
```

Так не помогло

```
if (node.collection_node.Contains(i) != true)
{
    node.collection_node.Add(i);
}
```

Comment: есть какие-нибудь ограничения на подузлы?

Comment: что вы понимаете под ограничением?

Comment: Все узлы типа Node.

Comment: какое-нибудь правило по которому один узел является владельцем других? например, они все меньше его.

Comment: нет............ Но могу уровни пронумеровать от материнского к дочернему и прописать в Node `public int level { get; set; }`

Comment: узлы у которых имя и текст с совпадают, но при этом различаются коллекции  - является  равными?

Comment: Да, равными. Но коллекци внутри них нужно нужно тоже сравнить и объединить.

Comment: тогда нет - они не равны :) значит надо просто сравнивать все со всем. можете добавить вычисление хэш-кода для ускорения нахождения различных узлов.

Comment: А Хэшкод как добавить?

Comment: добавить метод, который возвращает хэш-код для конкретного объекта. вычислять хэш-код можете любым известным способом.

Comment: А что означает ваш термин _ветка узлов_?

Comment: Стоит добавить хотя бы пару тестовых примеров...

Comment: `ветка узлов` ничего не означает . В оригинале было ветки нод (node node_ser)